# How can I get only the children of my entity that are already in the context, and not go to the database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, dbcontext

Is there a way that I can loop through navigational children of an Entity I've just added to Entity Framework, and only perform functionality on the object if it is already in my context?  If it hasn't been loaded in the context, I do not want EF to query the database, instead I want to just skip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.Local` when performing your queries. For example:

```
var query = context.Blogs;
```

will perform a query on the database.

```
var query = context.Blogs.Local;
```

will not.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872) for a more in-depth discussion and example.